# Data Bound ToolStripComboBox SelectedIndexChaged returns the previous index

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a Data Bound `ToolStripComboBox.SelectedIndexChaged` to fill the data on a form. The problem is the form fills with data from the previous selection. If I re-select the `ComboBox` then the data in the form is correct.

My Code looks like this.

```
Private Sub tscbMainFindProject_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tscbMainFindProject.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim row As ProjectNameDataSet.ProjectNameRow
row = CType(CType(Me.ProjectNameBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row, ProjectNameDataSet.ProjectNameRow)
Jobs.JobDetailsTableAdapter.FillByProjectID(Jobs.JobDetailsDataSet.JobDetails, row.ProjectID)

End Sub
```

The Query returns the current the data based on the current `ProjectID`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `DoCmd.RunCommand` means it is vba or access-vb, **not** vb.net; please retag

Comment: This is a vb.net question. I've removed the comment that confused the question.